# How to retrieve the ios device screen resolution from the simctl command line

Tags: ios, command-line, ios-simulator, screen-resolution, simctl

I'm looking for a way to retrieve via the `xcrun simctl` command line the screen resolution of the devices.

I'v tried to list device types with `xcrun simctl list -j devicetypes` but unfortunately the resolution is not stored there...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way by digging, thanks to CodeBender solution, with `xcrun simctl io`

Use it this way (where the UDID is the device you want):

```
xcrun simctl io 80E6DAF5-A6EE-44F5-AAE6-561D58652C31 enumerate
```

It returns instantly this:

```
Port:
    UUID: 246D47F3-7BDA-42DE-B511-0C1BD0C1EBCF
    Class: Display
    Port Identifier: com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices.Display
    Power state: On
    Display class: 0
    Default width: 640
    Default height: 1136
    Default pixel format: 'BGRA'
    Display rotation:
        Angle              = 0 radians
```

Comment: Good catch, glad you found a better approach

Comment: Thanks to you! (You should have left your answer, it was also interesting I think)